# USB 3.0 drivers

Tags: drivers, usb, ubuntu-drivers

Can anyone tell me what exactly is the USB 3 driver that is incorporated in Ubuntu?  I'd like to look for a hardware that matches that driver exactly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no drivers in Linux, but the name of the USB 3.0 **module** is the `Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub`, which doesn't help you at all finding hardware that matches this module exactly... :(

That being said, if you want to buy hardware that has been tested on Ubuntu, just have a look at the [Canonical certification catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/). Which is called by *some other company which shall not be named* the "Hardware Compatibility List" or HCL for short.  **;-)**

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this is the information you need, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)